# Get history of remote connections for a user

Tags: windows, logging, kerberos

One of our disabled admin account credentials is still used to perform (failed) login attempts on some Windows servers from a bunch of other servers.
The login attempts were made using Kerberos authentication.

**Question**: How can identify on the source servers the scripts/applications reponsible for these attemps ? Which log source could be the more reliable ? Can I put some kind of listener for a particular username ?

At the moment I have been investigating in the Event Viewer of the source servers but cannot find any relevant information to my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to another post of [ner0](https://serverfault.com/users/330004/ner0) I have been able to identified the processes using the credentials with the following command:

```
schtasks /query /v /fo csv > sched_tasks.csv
```